# shouldChangeCharactersInRange doesn't get the last number

Tags: objective-c

I have this code that should catch exactly what the user types:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSLog(@"Catch -> %@",textfield.text);

}
```

But When the user digit the letter **A**, the console return me ('null'), When the user digit the letter **AB**, the console return me only the letter **A**, in this case the method shouldChangeCharactersInRange doesn't return the last letter that user types.

To change this I try to change my code to:

```
NSLog(@"Catch -> %@",string);
```

In this case, the console shows me only the last number. How can I solve this problem and pick the complete sentence that user digit?

Comment: That method is called before the text field is updated.

Comment: stotre textfield.text in some string variable and append the string on textfield.text you will not miss any Characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is called BEFORE the text field has changed.  If you speak English, you would have already known this just by reading the method name, one of the big advantages of Cocoa...

This method gives you a chance to say "NO, don't change the text in this text box!" or to change the text in the box before the change is made, or to change the text that will be added before it's added.

`textfield.text` won't reflect the change until after this method returns.

---

To catch the END of editing events for a textfield, put this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Where `yourTextField` is a reference to the text field of interest.

Now write the method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextfield *)textfield {
    NSLog(@"Catch -> %@", textfield.text);
}
```

Comment: Oh I see now, Im very glad for your answer thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This delegate method for me usually starts out like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    NSString *candidateString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
```

Now, `candidateString` will contain what you expect.  It's done this way so that any manner of input (even a paste into the middle of the text) can be understood before and after the text field's text is updated

Comment: Thanks you too for the answer +1 for you!

Comment: While this will technically work, `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` can be an expensive operation.  Using this method means that we're basically performing this operation twice every time the string needs to be modified, and if we never need to say `NO` to this (to prevent the change from happening), this is going to be kind of expensive relative to just looking post-change.